# Functional componenet in a class component React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

Hi I ve got the following functional component which by itself it works perfectly

```
function MeditationList({route, navigation}) {
  const adress = route.params;

  return (
    <View>
      <HeaderBar />
      <Text>
        You have a number of {JSON.stringify(adress.item.numMed)} meditations
      </Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

but when I am trying to include it in a class component it does not work giving me the following error

```
class PreScreen extends Component {
  meditationList = ({route}) => {
    const adress = route.params;

    return (
      <Text>
        You have a number of {JSON.stringify(adress.item.numMed)} meditations
      </Text>
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
          {this.meditationList()}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

I suppose is something silly mistake that I make. Thank you.

Comment: you are calling `this.meditationList()` without the expected argument `{route}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

props are not automatically injected to your methods. if you want to use route you should use this.props.route

```
class PreScreen extends Component {
  meditationList = () => {
    const adress = this.props.route.params;

    return (
      <Text>
        You have a number of {JSON.stringify(adress.item.numMed)} meditations
      </Text>
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
          {this.meditationList()}
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```